# php cart out of stock mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The following PHP validation code works however if i go back to products page to add more of the same product it can overrides saying **out' on cart page when quantity is not available**

The following shows an if statement that is linked to $cart session data along with $film quantity which is stored in a table.

For some reason  $film['quantity'] has a value of 1 so if quantity >1 added to cart 'out' shows which is wrong?

```
    <?php $itemcount = $_SESSION['itemcount'];


                if($cart[QUANTITY][$i] > $table['quantity'] ) { ?>
      <span  style="font-family:'arial';">Out </span>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think you need to display the available product if some body ask you more than the available right ?

Comment: i have done that I have a products page and carts page. im trying to add validation so a customer cant add more product then are in stock.

Answer (score 1):

With the code shown it is hard to say what the issue is. However there is a good suspect here:

```
if($cart[QUANTITY][$i] > $film['quantity'] ) {
```

I suspect it should be:

```
if($cart[$i]['QUANTITY'] > $film['quantity'] ) {
```

Other things that might be amiss:

1. Have you `session_start()`ed?
2. Is the key `QUANTITY` not `quantity` (Case is important)
3. Do you happen to have defined a constant `QUANTITY` somewhere? (Quotes are important)

Comment: I have used at the beginning session_start() Quantity and quantity are different. Quantity is storing session for the cart. quantity is from the database table film which store how many are available in stock? $film['quantity'] is not displaying correctly that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you:

```
<?php

  echo $product_image; 
  echo $product_count;
  echo $product_price;
  echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
  echo "<input type='text' name='product_shopping_count' />";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='".$product_id."' />";  
  echo "<input type='submit' name='addCart' value='AddCart' />";
  echo "</form>";
  if(isset($_POST['addCart']){
     if(isset($_SESSION['cart']){
        $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
        if($cart[$_POST['product_id']]['quantity']>$product_count){
           echo "<span  style='font-family:arial;font-size:16px;'>Out </span>";
        }else if($_POST['product_shopping_count']>$product_count){
           echo "<span  style='font-family:arial;font-size:16px;'>Out </span>";
        }else {
           $cart['product_id']= $_POST['product_id'];
           $cart['product_id']['quantity'] = $_POST['product_shopping_count'];
           $cart['product_id']['price'] = $product_price;
           $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; 
        }
     }
  }
?>
```

Comment: The above if statement was to display error message via divs when product 'out' . i already have an add to cart function so when I add your code it's causing errors Undefined index: product_id in , Undefined index: in,Undefined variable: product_count in, etc. Should I send you send my add to cart function because I think that where my problem is, when the same product is added to cart it doesn't update quantity. Like the following link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716235/php-sessions-shopping-cart-update-product-if-its-already-id-the-session

Comment: please, show  me function  "add to cart"  and function "product show" on the page product