# php session update product if id already in the session

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, session-variables

The following function is on carts page, after a user has added product from previous product page. The problem is I need the multidimensional array just to update quantity in cart for same product code being added.

**Can someone help me add an if statement so when the same productcode is added quantity increases?**

Like this answer however my add to cart is different. [PHP Sessions shopping cart: update product if it's already id the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716235/php-sessions-shopping-cart-update-product-if-its-already-id-the-session)

```
    function AddToCart()  
 {
 $cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : '';
 $itemcount = isset($_SESSION

 ['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0; 
  {
   $i = array_search($_POST['productcode'], $cart[PRODUCTCODE]);
     $cart[PRODUCTCODE] [$itemcount] = $_POST['productcode']; 
     $cart[PRODUCTNAME] [$itemcount] =  $_POST['productname']; 
     $cart[QUANTITY][$itemcount] = intval($_POST['quantity']); 
     $cart[PRICE][$itemcount] = $_POST['price']; 

 $itemcount = $itemcount + 1; 
     if(strlen($error) == 0) { 
 $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart; 
 $_SESSION['itemcount'] = $itemcount; 
 } 
  return $error;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
//check for an existing match
$found = FALSE;
if($cart){
    $idx = 0;
    foreach($cart[PRODUCTCODE] as $idx => $product){
        if($product == $_POST['productcode']){
            $found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
}
//if we found a match
if($found){
    $cart[QUANTITY][$idx] += intval($_POST['quantity']);
}
//otherwise add new item
else{
    //your other code here
}
```

Comment: What variable is idx?

Comment: The array index at which a match was found. It's similar to your itemcount.

Comment: ive added got error 
Notice: Use of undefined constant product - assumed 'product' in

Comment: forgot the $ before the variable. Have edited answer to fix

Comment: which variable have you forgot $?

Comment: The product in `if($product == $_POST['productcode']){`. Just re-copy the answer.

Comment: it doesnt update quantity just adds new line for the same product like before?

Comment: Your current code adds a new array index for each new post. If you follow my directions and put your old code in the `else` statement then you'll get the desired result. It seems based on your comments that you're probably a bit of a beginner. Don't despair! The answer I've given you will work if you use it correctly. Step through it a bit at a time in your head or draw a diagram of the flow to better picture what's happening.

Comment: i am im despairing at the moment what part of my code do i put in your other code?

Comment: Let's take this out of the comments. Here's a temporary chat we can use to help you out. http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/for+paul?password=

Comment: Great answer OffTheBricks